# Haskell higher order function problem

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

**Current Code**

I have two functions as

```
f1::Int->Int->Int
f1 a b | a==1 &&  b==1 = 1
       | otherwise = 0
```

applying this function to a `[Int]` by a another function

```
f2::[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
f2 a b = map f1 a b
```

**Error**

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : map f1 c d
*** Term           : map
*** Type           : (e -> f) -> [e] -> [f]
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

**Conclution**

actually what i requied is to apply the `f1` which perform to a `Int` to a `[Int]` using `f2`
is this problem can solved in **higher order functions** ?  or any other method ? ... or how can i transform `f2` to be a higher order function to take `f1` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to apply the function to two list you need a different function, namely zipWith.

```
f2 a b = zipWith f1 a b
```